# How to interpret wavelet results in weka

Tags: weka, wavelet, haar-wavelet

I entered my input data in CSV format into Weka software. Then I applied the wavelet to the data. The output of this work was Haar1, Haar2, Haar3, and Haar4. I wanted to ask what is the meaning of these outputs. Does it mean that wavelet grade 4 is considered? What is the default level of wavelet in Weka?

6 parameters were considered as modeling inputs and one parameter as modeling output. From the filtering section of the Weka software, the Haar wavelet was applied to the data. After applying this filter to the data, 5 input parameters were converted into 8 Haar. What is the meaning of this Haar and how should it be interpreted? Where should I find the degree of wavelet in Waka software?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Wavelets require the number of columns in the data to be powers of 2, otherwise they pad it to the next power. In your case, the data contains 5 columns and got padded to 8.

Then the [Haar wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet) transform got applied, hence generating new attributes of format `HaarX` with X ranging from 1 to 8 ([link to Weka source code](https://git.cms.waikato.ac.nz/weka/weka/-/blob/main/trunk/packages/internal/wavelet/src/main/java/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Wavelet.java#L602)).